# Relative probability

Tags: probability

I've a question that already was answered by my physics teacher at University but he didn't really satisfied me. So the point is:
If i throw two coins contemporary with same start conditions, that means there are no things that can fake the result, each configuration will be equiprobable, so I'll have P=1/4 for head or tail. so that is the case when they are contemporary, but once I throw them, always with the same start conditions, but in different time,  P=1/2 probability for each side to come. So the question is what if I toss them contemporary in a statis reference system and I watch them trough a system that is going fast as or faster the speed of light, I'll loose the concept of contemporarity and I'll see them out of phase, so the probability is not 1/4 but 1/2. So the problem is which probability is correct?
The fact is that the problem came out thinking about the law of large numbers and the fact that if I define the probability with some sort of frequency it will be time-dependent. But then, when I did ask it to my professor, he said that probability is time-indipendent, so I'm confused.
I feel there is a hole in the question, like something is missing or I just mixed up things, but I can't really figure it out.

Thanks in advaced.
I'm sorry for my bad English, I just hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: It makes no difference whether the two coins are tossed at the same time or not, so viewing them from different inertial frames makes no difference. I think this really belongs on the MathSE.

Comment: If I toss two coins I have 4 possible outcomes, 2 for each coin, if I toss them separatly I'll have 2 possible outcomes for each one of them, isn't it like that? It was told so by my teacher and classmates, but I may mesunderstood. If you say that it is a mere math problem, maybe I should review some points because I still don't get it. Thank you in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the probability of an event occurring for coin 1 as $P_1(\text{event})$ and for coin 2 as $P_2(\text{event})$. Note that the indices are purely to discriminate between the coins, the actual probabilities are the same (assuming the coins are identical). So $P_1(H) = P_2(H) = 1/2 = P_2(T) = P_1(T)$, where $H$ denotes the event of getting heads and $T$ denotes the event of getting tails.

Now recall that, for two independent events $A$ and $B$, the probability of both $A$ and $B$ occurring is simply the product of the separate probabilities: $P(A\&B) = P(A)P(B)$. The probability of getting *two* heads from throwing both coins is therefore $P_1(H)P_2(H) = 1/4$, **regardless of when the coins were thrown**.

Your confusion probably stems from incorrectly thinking that $P(A\&B) = P(A)P(B)$ requires $A$ and $B$ to happen simultaneously. This is not the case. There is no time dependence.

Comment: I think I got it, your explanation seems quite clear to me. I don't know why, but it is harder than what I throught,and I'm not the only one in the class thinking that, yet it seems so intuitive. Thank you.